# Node js process suddenly jump to 100% CPU usage

Tags: javascript, node.js, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, strace

We are facing a problem with our Node js (v0.10.26) application with CLUSTER module on ubuntu amazon EC2 (c3.large) instance that nearly everyday we get a 100% cpu spike (on the workers) suddenly and it never goes down until we restart our application the problem is that these spikes happens randomly and at weird times (at 3AM) when the traffic is minimal, when i looked at the logs i found that the logs stopped recording any requests probably because the node js app stopped working, what i did based on what i read so far is to do a strace on the process which was at 100% and check the output so i did and here is the output of my stack trace

```
gettimeofday({1418314214, 491214}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1418314214, 491327}, NULL) = 0
futex(0x7faad80008c8, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
gettimeofday({1418314214, 619975}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1418314214, 620055}, NULL) = 0
futex(0x7faad80008c8, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
mmap(0xfcc3b000000, 20480, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xfcc3b000000
mprotect(0xfcc3b005000, 4096, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0xfcc3b006000, 1019904, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xfcc3b006000
mprotect(0xfcc3b0ff000, 4096, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0xfcc3b100000, 20480, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xfcc3b100000
mprotect(0xfcc3b105000, 4096, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0xfcc3b106000, 1019904, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xfcc3b106000
mprotect(0xfcc3b1ff000, 4096, PROT_NONE) = 0
gettimeofday({1418314214, 731602}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1418314214, 731682}, NULL) = 0
futex(0x7faad80008c8, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
mmap(0xfcc3b200000, 20480, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xfcc3b200000
mprotect(0xfcc3b205000, 4096, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0xfcc3b206000, 1019904, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xfcc3b206000
mprotect(0xfcc3b2ff000, 4096, PROT_NONE) = 0
gettimeofday({1418314214, 835071}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1418314214, 835154}, NULL) = 0
futex(0x7faad80008c8, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
mmap(0xfcc3b300000, 20480, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xfcc3b300000
mprotect(0xfcc3b305000, 4096, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0xfcc3b306000, 1019904, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xfcc3b306000
mprotect(0xfcc3b3ff000, 4096, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0xfcc3b400000, 20480, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xfcc3b400000
mprotect(0xfcc3b405000, 4096, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0xfcc3b406000, 1019904, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xfcc3b406000
mprotect(0xfcc3b4ff000, 4096, PROT_NONE) = 0
gettimeofday({1418314214, 938991}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1418314214, 939072}, NULL) = 0
futex(0x7faad80008c8, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
mmap(0xfcc3b500000, 20480, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xfcc3b500000
mprotect(0xfcc3b505000, 4096, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0xfcc3b506000, 1019904, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xfcc3b506000
mprotect(0xfcc3b5ff000, 4096, PROT_NONE) = 0
gettimeofday({1418314215, 41662}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1418314215, 41744}, NULL) = 0
futex(0x7faad80008c8, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
mmap(0xfcc3b600000, 20480, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xfcc3b600000
mprotect(0xfcc3b605000, 4096, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0xfcc3b606000, 1019904, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xfcc3b606000
mprotect(0xfcc3b6ff000, 4096, PROT_NONE) = 0
gettimeofday({1418314215, 161306}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1418314215, 161408}, NULL) = 0
futex(0x7faad80008c8, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
mmap(0xfcc3b700000, 20480, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xfcc3b700000
mprotect(0xfcc3b705000, 4096, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0xfcc3b706000, 1019904, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xfcc3b706000
mprotect(0xfcc3b7ff000, 4096, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0xfcc3b800000, 20480, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xfcc3b800000
mprotect(0xfcc3b805000, 4096, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0xfcc3b806000, 1019904, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xfcc3b806000
mprotect(0xfcc3b8ff000, 4096, PROT_NONE) = 0
gettimeofday({1418314215, 287996}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1418314215, 288120}, NULL) = 0
futex(0x7faad80008c8, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
mmap(0xfcc3b900000, 20480, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xfcc3b900000
mprotect(0xfcc3b905000, 4096, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0xfcc3b906000, 1019904, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xfcc3b906000
mprotect(0xfcc3b9ff000, 4096, PROT_NONE) = 0
gettimeofday({1418314215, 472947}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1418314215, 473040}, NULL) = 0
futex(0x7faad80008c8, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
mmap(0xfcc3ba00000, 20480, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xfcc3ba00000
mprotect(0xfcc3ba05000, 4096, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0xfcc3ba06000, 1019904, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xfcc3ba06000
mprotect(0xfcc3baff000, 4096, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0xfcc3bb00000, 20480, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xfcc3bb00000
mprotect(0xfcc3bb05000, 4096, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0xfcc3bb06000, 1019904, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xfcc3bb06000
mprotect(0xfcc3bbff000, 4096, PROT_NONE) = 0
gettimeofday({1418314215, 593480}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1418314215, 593565}, NULL) = 0
futex(0x7faad80008c8, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
mmap(0xfcc3bc00000, 20480, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xfcc3bc00000
mprotect(0xfcc3bc05000, 4096, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0xfcc3bc06000, 1019904, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xfcc3bc06000
mprotect(0xfcc3bcff000, 4096, PROT_NONE) = 0
gettimeofday({1418314215, 696233}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1418314215, 696315}, NULL) = 0
futex(0x7faad80008c8, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
mmap(0xfcc3bd00000, 20480, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xfcc3bd00000
mprotect(0xfcc3bd05000, 4096, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0xfcc3bd06000, 1019904, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xfcc3bd06000
mprotect(0xfcc3bdff000, 4096, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0xfcc3be00000, 20480, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xfcc3be00000
mprotect(0xfcc3be05000, 4096, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0xfcc3be06000, 1019904, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xfcc3be06000
mprotect(0xfcc3beff000, 4096, PROT_NONE) = 0
gettimeofday({1418314215, 875801}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1418314215, 875898}, NULL) = 0
futex(0x7faad80008c8, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
mmap(0xfcc3bf00000, 20480, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xfcc3bf00000
mprotect(0xfcc3bf05000, 4096, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0xfcc3bf06000, 1019904, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xfcc3bf06000
mprotect(0xfcc3bfff000, 4096, PROT_NONE) = 0
gettimeofday({1418314216, 38282}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1418314216, 38365}, NULL) = 0
futex(0x7faad80008c8, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
mmap(0xfcc3c000000, 20480, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xfcc3c000000
mprotect(0xfcc3c005000, 4096, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0xfcc3c006000, 1019904, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xfcc3c006000
mprotect(0xfcc3c0ff000, 4096, PROT_NONE) = 0
gettimeofday({1418314216, 255472}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1418314216, 255552}, NULL) = 0
futex(0x7faad80008c8, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
mmap(0xfcc3c100000, 20480, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xfcc3c100000
mprotect(0xfcc3c105000, 4096, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0xfcc3c106000, 1019904, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xfcc3c106000
mprotect(0xfcc3c1ff000, 4096, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0xfcc3c200000, 20480, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xfcc3c200000
mprotect(0xfcc3c205000, 4096, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0xfcc3c206000, 1019904, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xfcc3c206000
mprotect(0xfcc3c2ff000, 4096, PROT_NONE) = 0
gettimeofday({1418314216, 390157}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1418314216, 390240}, NULL) = 0
futex(0x7faad80008c8, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
mmap(0xfcc3c300000, 20480, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xfcc3c300000
mprotect(0xfcc3c305000, 4096, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0xfcc3c306000, 1019904, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xfcc3c306000
mprotect(0xfcc3c3ff000, 4096, PROT_NONE) = 0
gettimeofday({1418314216, 532144}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1418314216, 532225}, NULL) = 0
futex(0x7faad80008c8, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
mmap(0xfcc3c400000, 20480, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xfcc3c400000
mprotect(0xfcc3c405000, 4096, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0xfcc3c406000, 1019904, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xfcc3c406000
mprotect(0xfcc3c4ff000, 4096, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0xfcc3c500000, 20480, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xfcc3c500000
mprotect(0xfcc3c505000, 4096, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0xfcc3c506000, 1019904, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xfcc3c506000
mprotect(0xfcc3c5ff000, 4096, PROT_NONE) = 0
gettimeofday({1418314216, 676703}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1418314216, 676786}, NULL) = 0
futex(0x7faad80008c8, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
mmap(0xfcc3c600000, 20480, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xfcc3c600000
mprotect(0xfcc3c605000, 4096, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0xfcc3c606000, 1019904, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xfcc3c606000
mprotect(0xfcc3c6ff000, 4096, PROT_NONE) = 0
gettimeofday({1418314216, 832680}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1418314216, 845863}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1418314216, 855742}, NULL) = 0
mmap(0xfcc3c600000, 1048576, PROT_NONE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_NORESERVE, -1, 0) = 0xfcc3c600000
mmap(0xfcc3c500000, 1048576, PROT_NONE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_NORESERVE, -1, 0) = 0xfcc3c500000
mmap(0xfcc3c400000, 1048576, PROT_NONE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_NORESERVE, -1, 0) = 0xfcc3c400000
mmap(0xfcc3c300000, 1048576, PROT_NONE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_NORESERVE, -1, 0) = 0xfcc3c300000
mmap(0xfcc3c200000, 1048576, PROT_NONE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_NORESERVE, -1, 0) = 0xfcc3c200000
mmap(0xfcc3c100000, 1048576, PROT_NONE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_NORESERVE, -1, 0) = 0xfcc3c100000
mmap(0xfcc3c000000, 1048576, PROT_NONE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_NORESERVE, -1, 0) = 0xfcc3c000000
mmap(0xfcc3bf00000, 1048576, PROT_NONE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_NORESERVE, -1, 0) = 0xfcc3bf00000
mmap(0xfcc3be00000, 1048576, PROT_NONE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_NORESERVE, -1, 0) = 0xfcc3be00000
mmap(0xfcc3bd00000, 1048576, PROT_NONE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_NORESERVE, -1, 0) = 0xfcc3bd00000
mmap(0xfcc3bc00000, 1048576, PROT_NONE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_NORESERVE, -1, 0) = 0xfcc3bc00000
mmap(0xfcc3bb00000, 1048576, PROT_NONE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_NORESERVE, -1, 0) = 0xfcc3bb00000
mmap(0xfcc3ba00000, 1048576, PROT_NONE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_NORESERVE, -1, 0) = 0xfcc3ba00000
mmap(0xfcc3b900000, 1048576, PROT_NONE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_NORESERVE, -1, 0) = 0xfcc3b900000
mmap(0xfcc3b800000, 1048576, PROT_NONE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_NORESERVE, -1, 0) = 0xfcc3b800000
mmap(0xfcc3b700000, 1048576, PROT_NONE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_NORESERVE, -1, 0) = 0xfcc3b700000
mmap(0xfcc3b600000, 1048576, PROT_NONE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_NORESERVE, -1, 0) = 0xfcc3b600000
mmap(0xfcc3b500000, 1048576, PROT_NONE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_NORESERVE, -1, 0) = 0xfcc3b500000
mmap(0xfcc3b400000, 1048576, PROT_NONE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_NORESERVE, -1, 0) = 0xfcc3b400000
mmap(0xfcc3b300000, 1048576, PROT_NONE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_NORESERVE, -1, 0) = 0xfcc3b300000
mmap(0xfcc3b200000, 1048576, PROT_NONE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_NORESERVE, -1, 0) = 0xfcc3b200000
mmap(0xfcc3b100000, 1048576, PROT_NONE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_NORESERVE, -1, 0) = 0xfcc3b100000
mmap(0xfcc3b000000, 1048576, PROT_NONE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_NORESERVE, -1, 0) = 0xfcc3b000000
gettimeofday({1418314216, 872832}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1418314216, 878758}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1418314216, 878857}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1418314216, 878928}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1418314216, 878996}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1418314216, 879065}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1418314216, 879154}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1418314216, 879648}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1418314216, 879718}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1418314216, 880313}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1418314216, 880383}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1418314216, 880452}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1418314216, 880521}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1418314216, 880590}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1418314216, 880658}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1418314216, 885737}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1418314216, 887874}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1418314216, 887965}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1418314216, 888056}, NULL) = 0
futex(0x7faad80008c8, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
gettimeofday({1418314217, 8997}, NULL)  = 0
gettimeofday({1418314217, 9096}, NULL)  = 0
futex(0x7faad80008c8, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
gettimeofday({1418314217, 115505}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1418314217, 115588}, NULL) = 0
futex(0x7faad80008c8, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
gettimeofday({1418314217, 217206}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1418314217, 217287}, NULL) = 0
futex(0x7faad80008c8, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
gettimeofday({1418314217, 315058}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1418314217, 315137}, NULL) = 0
futex(0x7faad80008c8, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
gettimeofday({1418314217, 412213}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1418314217, 412294}, NULL) = 0
futex(0x7faad80008c8, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
mmap(0xfcc3c700000, 20480, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xfcc3c700000
mprotect(0xfcc3c705000, 4096, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0xfcc3c706000, 1019904, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xfcc3c706000
mprotect(0xfcc3c7ff000, 4096, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0xfcc3c800000, 20480, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xfcc3c800000
mprotect(0xfcc3c805000, 4096, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0xfcc3c806000, 1019904, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xfcc3c806000
mprotect(0xfcc3c8ff000, 4096, PROT_NONE) = 0
gettimeofday({1418314217, 519206}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1418314217, 519289}, NULL) = 0
futex(0x7faad80008c8, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
mmap(0xfcc3c900000, 20480, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xfcc3c900000
mprotect(0xfcc3c905000, 4096, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0xfcc3c906000, 1019904, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xfcc3c906000
mprotect(0xfcc3c9ff000, 4096, PROT_NONE) = 0
gettimeofday({1418314217, 653545}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1418314217, 653624}, NULL) = 0
futex(0x7faad80008c8, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
mmap(0xfcc3ca00000, 20480, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xfcc3ca00000
mprotect(0xfcc3ca05000, 4096, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0xfcc3ca06000, 1019904, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xfcc3ca06000
mprotect(0xfcc3caff000, 4096, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0xfcc3cb00000, 20480, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xfcc3cb00000
mprotect(0xfcc3cb05000, 4096, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0xfcc3cb06000, 1019904, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xfcc3cb06000
mprotect(0xfcc3cbff000, 4096, PROT_NONE) = 0
gettimeofday({1418314217, 757446}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1418314217, 757530}, NULL) = 0
futex(0x7faad80008c8, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
mmap(0xfcc3cc00000, 20480, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xfcc3cc00000
mprotect(0xfcc3cc05000, 4096, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0xfcc3cc06000, 1019904, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xfcc3cc06000
mprotect(0xfcc3ccff000, 4096, PROT_NONE) = 0
gettimeofday({1418314217, 880698}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1418314217, 880777}, NULL) = 0
futex(0x7faad80008c8, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
mmap(0xfcc3cd00000, 20480, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xfcc3cd00000
mprotect(0xfcc3cd05000, 4096, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0xfcc3cd06000, 1019904, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xfcc3cd06000
mprotect(0xfcc3cdff000, 4096, PROT_NONE) = 0
gettimeofday({1418314217, 996985}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1418314217, 997063}, NULL) = 0
futex(0x7faad80008c8, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
mmap(0xfcc3ce00000, 20480, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xfcc3ce00000
mprotect(0xfcc3ce05000, 4096, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0xfcc3ce06000, 1019904, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xfcc3ce06000
mprotect(0xfcc3ceff000, 4096, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0xfcc3cf00000, 20480, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xfcc3cf00000
mprotect(0xfcc3cf05000, 4096, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0xfcc3cf06000, 1019904, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xfcc3cf06000
mprotect(0xfcc3cfff000, 4096, PROT_NONE) = 0
gettimeofday({1418314218, 156422}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1418314218, 156512}, NULL) = 0
futex(0x7faad80008c8, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
mmap(0xfcc3d000000, 20480, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xfcc3d000000
mprotect(0xfcc3d005000, 4096, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0xfcc3d006000, 1019904, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xfcc3d006000
mprotect(0xfcc3d0ff000, 4096, PROT_NONE) = 0
gettimeofday({1418314218, 331075}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1418314218, 331155}, NULL) = 0
futex(0x7faad80008c8, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
mmap(0xfcc3d100000, 20480, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xfcc3d100000
mprotect(0xfcc3d105000, 4096, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0xfcc3d106000, 1019904, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xfcc3d106000
mprotect(0xfcc3d1ff000, 4096, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0xfcc3d200000, 20480, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xfcc3d200000
mprotect(0xfcc3d205000, 4096, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0xfcc3d206000, 1019904, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xfcc3d206000
mprotect(0xfcc3d2ff000, 4096, PROT_NONE) = 0
gettimeofday({1418314218, 469695}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1418314218, 469779}, NULL) = 0
futex(0x7faad80008c8, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
mmap(0xfcc3d300000, 20480, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xfcc3d300000
mprotect(0xfcc3d305000, 4096, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0xfcc3d306000, 1019904, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xfcc3d306000
mprotect(0xfcc3d3ff000, 4096, PROT_NONE) = 0
gettimeofday({1418314218, 572096}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1418314218, 572177}, NULL) = 0
futex(0x7faad80008c8, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
mmap(0xfcc3d400000, 20480, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xfcc3d400000
mprotect(0xfcc3d405000, 4096, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0xfcc3d406000, 1019904, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xfcc3d406000
mprotect(0xfcc3d4ff000, 4096, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0xfcc3d500000, 20480, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xfcc3d500000
mprotect(0xfcc3d505000, 4096, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0xfcc3d506000, 1019904, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xfcc3d506000
mprotect(0xfcc3d5ff000, 4096, PROT_NONE) = 0
gettimeofday({1418314218, 710743}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1418314218, 710827}, NULL) = 0
futex(0x7faad80008c8, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
mmap(0xfcc3d600000, 20480, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xfcc3d600000
mprotect(0xfcc3d605000, 4096, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0xfcc3d606000, 1019904, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xfcc3d606000
mprotect(0xfcc3d6ff000, 4096, PROT_NONE) = 0
gettimeofday({1418314218, 844711}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1418314218, 844795}, NULL) = 0
futex(0x7faad80008c8, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
mmap(0xfcc3d700000, 20480, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xfcc3d700000
mprotect(0xfcc3d705000, 4096, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0xfcc3d706000, 1019904, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xfcc3d706000
mprotect(0xfcc3d7ff000, 4096, PROT_NONE) = 0
gettimeofday({1418314218, 979663}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1418314218, 979743}, NULL) = 0
futex(0x7faad80008c8, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
mmap(0xfcc3d800000, 20480, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xfcc3d800000
mprotect(0xfcc3d805000, 4096, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0xfcc3d806000, 1019904, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xfcc3d806000
mprotect(0xfcc3d8ff000, 4096, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0xfcc3d900000, 20480, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xfcc3d900000
mprotect(0xfcc3d905000, 4096, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0xfcc3d906000, 1019904, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xfcc3d906000
mprotect(0xfcc3d9ff000, 4096, PROT_NONE) = 0
gettimeofday({1418314219, 128634}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1418314219, 128719}, NULL) = 0
futex(0x7faad80008c8, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
mmap(0xfcc3da00000, 20480, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xfcc3da00000
mprotect(0xfcc3da05000, 4096, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0xfcc3da06000, 1019904, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xfcc3da06000
mprotect(0xfcc3daff000, 4096, PROT_NONE) = 0
gettimeofday({1418314219, 264543}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1418314219, 264626}, NULL) = 0
futex(0x7faad80008c8, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
mmap(0xfcc3db00000, 20480, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xfcc3db00000
mprotect(0xfcc3db05000, 4096, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0xfcc3db06000, 1019904, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xfcc3db06000
mprotect(0xfcc3dbff000, 4096, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0xfcc3dc00000, 20480, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xfcc3dc00000
mprotect(0xfcc3dc05000, 4096, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0xfcc3dc06000, 1019904, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xfcc3dc06000
mprotect(0xfcc3dcff000, 4096, PROT_NONE) = 0
gettimeofday({1418314219, 400804}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1418314219, 400886}, NULL) = 0
futex(0x7faad80008c8, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
mmap(0xfcc3dd00000, 20480, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xfcc3dd00000
mprotect(0xfcc3dd05000, 4096, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0xfcc3dd06000, 1019904, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xfcc3dd06000
mprotect(0xfcc3ddff000, 4096, PROT_NONE) = 0
gettimeofday({1418314219, 584835}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1418314219, 612381}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1418314219, 625079}, NULL) = 0
mmap(0xfcc3dd00000, 1048576, PROT_NONE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_NORESERVE, -1, 0) = 0xfcc3dd00000
mmap(0xfcc3dc00000, 1048576, PROT_NONE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_NORESERVE, -1, 0) = 0xfcc3dc00000
mmap(0xfcc3db00000, 1048576, PROT_NONE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_NORESERVE, -1, 0) = 0xfcc3db00000
mmap(0xfcc3da00000, 1048576, PROT_NONE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_NORESERVE, -1, 0) = 0xfcc3da00000
mmap(0xfcc3d900000, 1048576, PROT_NONE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_NORESERVE, -1, 0) = 0xfcc3d900000
mmap(0xfcc3d800000, 1048576, PROT_NONE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_NORESERVE, -1, 0) = 0xfcc3d800000
```

Aggregate view of strace: 
[image: strace agg. view]

[image: strace agg. view 2]

Also i tried to check the sockets connections using lsof command and here is what i found:
[image]

As you can see there are some CLOSE_WAIT connections, i don't know if its related or not.

and the output of TOP command:

[image]

in that situation only one of the workers went up to 100% while the other kept working normally 
Also when i did the lsof command on the other pid which was working normally i didn't find any CLOSE_WAIT in the connections.

Finally netstat output also shows alot of time waits during the cpu 100%.

If anyone faced a similar problem or can understand what is going on with my node js application please help!

Comment: Did you try upgrading to node v0.10.33?

Comment: Nope! do you think it can make a difference ?!

Comment: Possibly, it's always a good idea to test with the latest stable version when you run into issues like this.

Comment: Okay i will try to update and see how it goes, Thanks mscdex!

Comment: Tried to update node to 0.10.33 and still it happens!

Comment: when the problem happens, do you see any CPU steal time (%st) high or not? I have similar issue before (but not node.js application), and have to migrate the instance to another AZ in same region. Second, Could you paste `top` command output (at least first 10 lines)?

Comment: but i cant see how would that be a problem if in some cases one process only get the spike and the other worker doesn't! :S this problem is driving me mad really!

Comment: @KarimTarek Did you ever manage to figure out the problem? I am experiencing something very similar. CPU spikes start happening out of nowhere and it is only one cpu

Comment: @KorayGocmen Yes, after logging all the requests for a day or two based on a hope to capture the incident live, and lucky enough it happened. I started replaying the requests again and voila! i found the processor hop to 100% on our staging environment, and after some investigation found that the problem was related to express.js and some faulty URL that express then couldnt parse correctly and resulted in an infinite loop after testing it multiple times, so i handled faulty URLs in the middle ware layer and that solved the problem for me :)